# how do I determine whether a python script is imported as module or run as script?

Tags: python, module

The question is rather straightforward but not answered by searching. How do I determine in a python script whether this script is imported as a module or run as a script? Is there a difference at all in python?

The problem is, that I want to evaluate the command line parameters only if run as a script, but not if the module is only imported to use it in another script. (I want to be able to use one script as both library and program.) I am afraid the vanilla way would be to build the lib and a second script that uses it, but I'd like to have a second option for small tool/libs.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

from python [docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts):

> When you run a Python module with
>
> python fibo.py
>
> the code in the module will be
>   executed, just as if you imported it,
>   but with the `__name__` set to
>   `"__main__"`. That means that by adding
>   this code at the end of your module:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Running as a script
```

you can make the file usable as a script as well as an importable module, because the code that parses the command line only runs if the module is executed as the “main” file

Comment: this looks slightly magic but is actually a completely standard idiom. You will also be \_\_main\_\_ if you are a module invoked by 'python -m somemodule'.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out by @bobince:

> You will also be `__main__` if you are a module invoked by `python -m somemodule`

Let's suppose you have a Python file `bar.py` and an empty `__init__.py`, both inside a folder called `foo`:

```sh
$ tree
.
└── foo
    ├── __init__.py
    └── bar.py

$ cat foo/__init__.py
```

The Python code blocks below are the content of `foo/bar.py`.

### Using `__name__` (not working)

```py
print('Code executed as a %s' % 'script' if __name__ == '__main__' else 'module')
```

This will produce:

```sh
$ python foo/bar.py
Code executed as a script

$ python -m foo.bar
Code executed as a script
```

### Solution 1: using [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#vars) and [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.modules)

```py
import sys
mod_name = vars(sys.modules[__name__])['__package__']
print('Code executed as a ' + ('module named %s' % mod_name if mod_name else 'script'))
```

This will produce:

```sh
$ python foo/bar.py
Code executed as a module named foo

$ python -m foo.bar
Code executed as a script
```

### Solution 2: Using a try-except block on module import

```py
import sys
try:
    import foo
    print('Code executed as a module')
except ImportError:
    print('Code executed as a script')
    # Code will fail here, but you can still print a comprehensive error message before exiting:
    print('Usage: python -m foo.bar')
    sys.exit()
```

This will produce:

```sh
$ python foo/bar.py
Code executed as a module

$ python -m foo.bar
Code executed as a script
Usage: python -m foo.bar
```

Comment: When using `python -m foo.bar`, you are running the file as a module, not importing it. It can still accept command line arguments.