# How to determine if a scala module is run as script

Tags: scala

How do I determine if a Scala module is opened as script or if it is regularly imported?

This question is about the same issue as previous Python question:
[how do I determine whether a python script is imported as module or run as script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389044/how-do-i-determine-whether-a-python-script-is-imported-as-module-or-run-as-script)
but for **Scala**

Comment: I am not sure to understand why there's a negative vote.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need a quick hack for personal use, you can launch the Scala interpreter with a shell script that also sets an environment variable indicating that the interpreter is running.

Also, keep in mind that there's a difference between Scala and Python that makes the question somewhat moot: In Scala, code expressions can't appear at the top level, unless it's a Scala script. So you'll never really have the ambiguity of writing a Scala script and then wondering if it's being executed some other way.

Answer (score 1):

All Scala modules are imported regularly, because there is no such thing as opening as a script.

Answer (score 0):

Scala doesn't have the equivalent of Python's `__main__` as far as I know so it can't be done in the same way.  But I argue you shouldn't be doing this anyway - just write tests for your module or write a script that imports the module.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty hack could be to throw and exception and get the trace. You can then examine it to try to guess the context. For example a method like:

```
def stackTrace: Array[StackTraceElement] =
  try {
    1/0 // cause exception
    Array() //Never executed
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => e.getStackTrace
  }
```

Will return the full stack trace as an array of [`StackTraceElement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html).

However, writing the trace analysis code will be tedious and I don't see any situation where it may be worth of it...

Comment: Thanks, I never noticed that method.