# How do I determine whether a julia script is included as module or run as script?

Tags: julia

I would like to know how in the [Julia](https://julialang.org) language, I can determine if a `file.jl` is run as script, such as in the call:

```
bash$ julia file.jl
```

It must only in this case start a function `main`, for example. Thus I could use `include('file.jl')`, without actually executing the function.

To be specific, I am looking for something similar answered already [in a python question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389044/how-do-i-determine-whether-a-python-script-is-imported-as-module-or-run-as-scrip#1389048):

```
def main():
    # does something

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Edit:
To be more specific, the method `Base.isinteractive` (see [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/detect-if-running-as-script/8818)) is not solving the problem, when using `include('file.jl')` from within a non-interactive (e.g. script) environment.

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/572 is also related, but solves the problem in an interactive session only

Answer (score 4):

The global constant `PROGRAM_FILE` contains the script name passed to Julia from the command line (it does not change when `include` is called).

On the other hand `@__FILE__` macro gives you a name of the file where it is present.

For instance if you have a files:

*a.jl*

```
println(PROGRAM_FILE)
println(@__FILE__)
include("b.jl")
```

*b.jl*

```
println(PROGRAM_FILE)
println(@__FILE__)
```

You have the following behavior:

```
$ julia a.jl
a.jl
D:\a.jl
a.jl
D:\b.jl

$ julia b.jl
b.jl
D:\b.jl
```

In summary:

- `PROGRAM_FILE` tells you what is the file name that Julia was started with;
- `@__FILE__` tells you in what file actually the macro was called.

Comment: So a statement like `basename(PROGRAM_FILE) == basename(@__FILE__)` seems to return `true` for called as script and `false` for e.g. include?

Comment: In general yes. But you might have a problem if you have two files with the same name in different directories.

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr version:**

```
if !isdefined(:__init__) || Base.function_module(__init__) != MyModule
  main()
end
```

---

**Explanation:**

There seems to be some confusion. Python and Julia work very differently in terms of their "modules" (even though the two use the same term, in principle they are different).

In python, a source file is either a module or a script, depending on how you chose to "load" / "run" it: the boilerplate exists to detect the environment in which the source code was run, by querying the `__name__` of the embedding module at the time of execution. E.g. if you have a file called `mymodule.py`, it you import it normally, then within the module definition the variable `__name__` automatically gets set to the value `mymodule`; but if you ran it as a standalone script (effectively "dumping" the code into the "main" module), the `__name__` variable is that of the global scope, namely `__main__`. This difference gives you the ability to detect *how* a python file was ran, so you could act slightly differently in each case, and this is exactly what the boilerplate does.

In julia, however, a module is defined *explicitly as code*. Running a file that contains a `module` declaration will load that module regardless of whether you did `using` or `include`; however in the former case, the module will not be reloaded if it's already on the workspace, whereas in the latter case it's as if you "redefined" it.

Modules can have initialisation code via the special `__init__()` function, whose job is to only run the first time a module is loaded (e.g. when imported via a using statement). So one thing you could do is have a standalone script, which you could either `include` directly to run as a standalone script, or `include` it within the scope of a `module` definition, and have it detect the presence of module-specific variables such that it behaves differently in each case. But it would still have to be a standalone file, separate from the main module definition.

If you want the module to do stuff, that the standalone script shouldn't, this is easy: you just have something like this:

```
module MyModule
  __init__() = # do module specific initialisation stuff here
  include("MyModule_Implementation.jl")
end
```

If you want the reverse situation, you need a way to detect whether you're running inside the module or not. You could do this, e.g. by detecting the presence of a suitable `__init__()` function, belonging to that particular module. For example:

```
### in file "MyModule.jl"
module MyModule
  export fun1, fun2;
  __init__() = print("Initialising module ...");
  include("MyModuleImplementation.jl");
end
```

```
### in file "MyModuleImplementation.jl"
fun1(a,b) = a + b;
fun2(a,b) = a * b;

main() = print("Demo of fun1 and fun2.     \n" *
               "  fun1(1,2) = $(fun1(1,2)) \n" *
               "  fun2(1,2) = $(fun2(1,2)) \n");

if !isdefined(:__init__) || Base.function_module(__init__) != MyModule
  main()
end
```

If `MyModule` is loaded as a module, the `main` function in `MyModuleImplementation.jl` will not run.

If you run `MyModuleImplementation.jl` as a standalone script, the `main` function will run.

So this is a way to achieve something close to the effect you want; but it's very different to saying running a module-defining file as either a module or a standalone script; I don't think you can simply "strip" the `module` instruction from the code and run the module's "contents" in such a manner in julia.

Comment: Unfortunately this code gets me `ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: isdefined: too few arguments (expected 2)`

Comment: @wulftone this answer is from 2018, presumably an earlier version of julia, which has changed rapidly since. There's probably been some minor syntactical change to the `isdefined` function (e.g. having to specify the module explicitly). Have a look at the documentation of `isdefined`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is available at the official Julia docs [FAQ](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#How-do-I-check-if-the-current-file-is-being-run-as-the-main-script?). I am copy/pasting it here because this question comes up as the first hit on some search engines. It would be nice if people found the answer on the first-hit site.

> ## How do I check if the current file is being run as the main script?
>
> When a file is run as the main script using `julia file.jl` one might want to activate extra functionality like command line argument handling. A way to determine that a file is run in this fashion is to check if `abspath(PROGRAM_FILE) == @__FILE__` is `true`.

Comment: Using `abspath()` solved my problem with inconsistent path format for `PROGRAM_FILE`.