# Unable to run Base.compilecache: "not found in path"

Tags: compilation, julia

I'm now trying to precompile a Julia module so that it may run faster. However, it seems strange to me that writing `__precompile__()` before the module declaration doesn't seem to have produced any cache file in the folder.

Then, I tried to call the function `Base.compilecache` with the following steps:

1. Launch the REPL in the project folder
2. `include("M.jl")`
3. `Base.compilecache("M")`

However, even though the first two steps finish without problems and that I can actually run the functions defined within the module, the third step complains "ERROR: ArgumentError: M not found in path", and I still can't seem to generate any cache for the module.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: btw, I assume this is just a typo in the question itself, but the instruction is `__precompile__()`, _not_ `__precompile()__`

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Sure, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiled modules are produced in a user-defined place, in linux typically `~/.julia/lib/v0.6/`. I'm sure if you look in there you will find `.ji` files corresponding to precompiled versions of your modules. Remove one and try importing again in a julia session to confirm that it will attempt to precompile all over again; if it does, it means your `__precompile__()` directive is working.

Furthermore, be careful to `push!` the path of your custom module (i.e. the source code `.jl` part, not the path for the precompiled `.ji` files) to the `LOAD_PATH` (i.e. `push!(LOAD_PATH, "./")` ) if this is not 'installed' in the default place (typically `~/.julia/v0.6/`). Julia needs access to both when you're about to import the module.

(PS. you should also see a Precompilation occuring if you update your module)

Comment: I just looked into it but I don't see my module, only some other libraries. What could be the cause of this? Might there be something that makes a module uncompilable?

Comment: ah, sorry, just spotted the exact wording in your question. Do not _include_ the module. `import` it. Precompilation checks, I believe, only take place when you attempt to `import` or `using` a module. If you simply `include` it, essentially you're dumping code into your current environment, so no attempt to precompile the module is made as far as I understand it.

Comment: this is also the point about "having to load your current path to the LOAD_PATH variable". Julia only looks for modules in the directories defined in the `LOAD_PATH`. To import a module that is sitting in your current directory you need to add this directory in the `LOAD_PATH` first, so that julia can find it.

Comment: Thanks. Using `import` finally let Julia precompile the module. However, does that mean anybody who wants to run this program will have to first alter the `LOAD_PATH` of their `julia` instance and then `import` the module? I guess the alternative would be to actually distribute the program as a Pkg and then ask the other users to install the Pkg. However, if the program is just a collection of scripts so far, then there seems to be no other way to do it?

Comment: Not at all. Yes, the best way is to create a package, but alternatively you can distribute your module along with a script (as per my answer to your other recent question), and prepare any `LOAD_PATH` instructions there, along with any other environmental variable initialisation, or parsing of inputs etc.

Comment: @xji also, you may also find [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49405645/4183191) somewhat relevant too.