# How to know my Python script is being run by another script or directly in a shell?

Tags: python

I have this Python script for formatting and coloring output:

```
def error(message):
    print(f"\033[91m{message}\033[00m")


def warning(message):
    print(f"\033[93m{message}\033[00m")


def info(message):
    print(f"\033[96m{message}\033[00m")


def success(message):
    print(f"\033[92m{message}\033[00m")
```

And it works great when I write messages directly to the terminal.

However, some of my scripts are used indirectly in other shell scripts, and in that case, my output won't work properly.

For example, I have a Python script to find out the name of the OS. It's called `GetOs` and when executed, it would print `Ubuntu` in a blue color.

Now when I want to use this Python script in my Shell script as follow:

```
if [[ $(GetOs) == Ubuntu ]]; then
   echo "This feature is not supported on Ubuntu"
fi
```

it fails. The equality operator won't work because the `$(GetOs)` would return a blue result to the stdout.

Is it possible for me to conditionally color messages in my `Message.py` file? To know if it's being called from another script or directly from the terminal?

Comment: Did you try giving your Python program a command-line option, so that the shell script can explicitly tell it not to colour the messages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I determine whether a python script is imported as module or run as script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389044/how-do-i-determine-whether-a-python-script-is-imported-as-module-or-run-as-scrip)

Comment: A better question to ask is "is standard output connected to a terminal"? But the simplest solution of all is to remove the annoying color coding.

Answer (score 2):

Your real question is how your script can determine whether if the standard output is connected to a terminal, and then and only then it should wrap any given output in color codes.

For that purpose you can use the [`isatty`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.isatty) method of the file object of the standard output, which returns `True` when the standard output is connected to a terminal, or `False` if it's redirected to a file or another process:

```
import sys

def info(message):
    if sys.stdout.isatty():
        print(f"\033[91m{message}\033[00m")
    else:
        print(message)
```